# Apache .htaccess rewrite

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi guys,

I've got the following problem with multilang WordPress installation and I wonder whether it can be resolved not by altering the WordPress installation but by rewriting rules for Apache webserver.

The website can display the content for various languages correctly in this manner:

```
Czech language content on:
http://www.example.com/cs/
http://www.example.com/cs/some-czech-page-name/
...

Slovak language content on:
http://www.example.com/sk/
http://www.example.com/sk/some-slovak-page-name/
...

English language content on:
http://www.example.com/en/
http://www.example.com/en/some-english-page-name/
...
```

Now, is it possible to modify .htaccess in order that the contents for various languages are displayed at various domains? I mean something like this:

```
Czech language content on:
http://www.example.cz/
http://www.example.cz/some-czech-page-name/
...

Slovak language content on:
http://www.example.sk/
http://www.example.sk/some-slovak-page-name/
...

English language content on:
http://www.example.com/
http://www.example.com/some-english-page-name/
...
```

Comment: I think it would be easier to change this in WP, than in apache. Maybe this helps: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/multisite-multidomain-same-content-localized-wp-theme . It might be useful to know how you have implemented your multi-language WP-setup.

Comment: I have chosen the [Polylang](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/polylang/) WordPress plugin which works great. It can assign pages/post/assets to particular language. But it doesn't support multi-domain installation (the topic was discussed at the author's blog about month ago I think). Now the client decide to go with multi-domain web sites... and it turns out that the chosen implementation is not the best solution for this task... Thanks a lot for the link anyway!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.sk
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sk
RewriteRule .* http://domain.com/sk/$0 [P,L]
#repeat for other domains
```

The `P` is for proxy, as otherwise WP and Polylang can't parse the url.

Comment: `[Fri Mar 08 22:19:45 2013] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.` Looks like I'll have to contact the hosting provider.

Answer (score 0):

This finally works as expected.

```
RewriteEngine On

# EXAMPLE.COM
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cs/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sk/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [P,L]

# EXAMPLE.CZ
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.example.cz
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/cs/$1 [P,L]

# EXAMPLE.SK
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.example.sk
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/sk/$1 [P,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

However there were some template edits necessary in order that everything works fine.